# Codeigniter: delete function in model not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is this wrong?

I get this error when I run the following code. I just want to write the delete function in the model in a way that I can reuse it.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMP\application\controllers\Student.php on line 101
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Parsing Error
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
>
> Filename: controllers/Student.php
>
> Line Number: 101
>
> Backtrace:

Model

```
   function delete_by_id($id,$table)
{
    $this->db->where($id);
    $this->db->delete($table);
}
```

Controller

```
 public function student_delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Model_Action');
    $this->Model_Action->delete_by_id('p_id'=>$id, 'parent');
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

Comment: `$this->Model_Action->delete_by_id('p_id'=>$id, 'parent');` should be `$this->Model_Action->delete_by_id(['p_id'=>$id], 'parent');`

Comment: Thank you, But unfortunately, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change your array syntax like below:

```
public function student_delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Model_Action');
    $this->Model_Action->delete_by_id('p_id = '. $id, 'parent');
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it didnt work